# Mulesoft cloudhub timeout although it works well locally

Tags: mule, mule-component, cloudhub

Mule cloudhub times out only on HTTPs.

I have a mule http listener in my flow. It works all right locally as well as on the cloudhub upon deployment.

To add security, I switched on HTTPs and I did so as per this blog.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/building-an-https-service

Works fine locally.But once it's deployed to cloudhub, it starts timing out with HTTP 504. I've even increased the idle time out to a pretty high value. But, it still times out.

Anyone faced this? would be great to get some solution for this.

Comment: IF you are using self-signed certificate you may need to import it to browser,try hittinh the api through browser.

Comment: Thanks. But, isn't the self signed cert just there to get the local code to compile and therefore deploy? Once deployed on to cloudhub, the api is strapped with cloudhub cert.

This is the cert I receive with the 504.


Subject: CN=*.cloudhub.io, O=MuleSoft Inc., L=San Francisco, ST=California, C=US

Comment: Can you please share your HTTPS listener configuration in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Reason 1) There is a hard timeout for the Mule Cloudhub which is 5 minutes. If your API is exceeding it then that's the reason for the time out in the cloud. As per my knowledge, it's not configurable/overwritable for each organization client.
You might have to look into a callback model here.

Reason 2) If your API not taking 5 minutes or more time for processing, then it might be something with the SSL configurations

Reason 3) If the above two items are good then this might be something with network connectivity. Please verify the firewall rules in this case.